# Reduced group $C^*$ algebra inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lie-groups, operator-algebras

This is part of the definition of constructing the reduced $C$-norm.

> Let $G$ be a locally compact hausdorff group, $\nu$ a  Haar measure that is both left and right invariant, $\xi\in B(L^2(G))$, Then we define $\pi(f):C_c(G) \rightarrow L^2(G)$ by
>   $$ \pi(f)(\xi) (\gamma) = \int_{\eta \in G} f(\gamma \eta^{-1}) \xi (\eta)  \, d\nu (\eta) $$

It is claimed that

> $$||\pi(f) \xi||_2 \le ||f||_1 ||\xi||_2$$
>   $\pi(f)$ can now be regarded as an operator $L^1(G) \rightarrow L^2(G)$.

How is this so? Moreover, it is claimed that

> $$||f||_r = || \pi(f)||$$

in fact defines a $C^*$ norm (rather than a seminorm) - is this true, and if so, how?

Comment: I am so sorry, I have edited the problem. I was reading a few sources at a time and got confused. I am now using: page 92 of this notes. https://math.dartmouth.edu/~dana/bookspapers/cstar.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have, using that convolution is commutative, [Minkowski's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality#Minkowski's_integral_inequality), and the invariance of $\nu$,
\begin{align}
\|\pi(f)\xi\|_2
&=\left(\int_G\left|\int_G g(\gamma\eta^{-1})f(\eta)\,d\nu(\eta) \right|^2\,d\nu(\gamma)\right)^{1/2} \\
&\leq\int_G\left(\int_G |g(\gamma\eta^{-1})|^2\,|f(\eta)|^2\,d\nu(\gamma) \right)^{1/2}\,d\nu(\eta)\\
&\leq\int_G|f(\eta)|^2\,\left(\int_G |g(\gamma\eta^{-1})|^2\,d\nu(\gamma) \right)^{1/2}\,d\nu(\eta)\\
&=\|f\|_1\,\|g\|_2.
\end{align}
If $\pi(f)=0$, then $f*\xi=0$ for all $\xi\in L^2(G)$ which implies that $f=0$, $\|\cdot\|_r$ is a norm.

As for C$^*$,
$$
\pi(f*g)\xi=(f*g)*\xi=f*(g*\xi)=\pi(f)\pi(g)\xi,
$$
so $\pi$ is multiplicative. After you check that $\pi(f^*)=\pi(f)^*$, you have that $\pi$ is a $*$-homomorphism. Then 
$$
\|f\|_r^2=\|\pi(f)\|^2=\|\pi(f)^*\pi(f)\|=\|\pi(f^*f)\|=\|f^*f\|_r.
$$